# Allow users to change password when using git-shell?

Tags: git

Is this possible, without having the users tell me their password?

Answer (score 2):

git-shell's [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html) has some information on using `git-shell-commands`.

You can try adding a link in their `git-shell-commands` directory to `passwd`.

`ln -s /path/to/passwd ~user/git-shell-commands/passwd`

Then you can have them run `git shell -c passwd` and change their passwords themselves.